# Translate-Z Mixing Order only Mobile

Tags: html, css

I'm having a weird problem with a website we are developing. This site has a parallax effect in it, and it's implemented without JavaScript using only translate z and scale (you can check this in http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/)

The problem we are having is that in chrome for desktop the site seems to be ok (you'll see the problem on the second picture):

[image: image-ok]

But when I turn "devide mode" on, this is what I see 90% of the times (also in mobile and also, most of the time, but not all the times):

[image: image-not-ok]

As you can see, the slider above "DESTACADOS" is gone, but if I click any button, or execute any action (click on button or link), the slider appears again.

The problem is kind of hard to pinpoint, so ask for whatever clarification or specification you need.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:**
I have tried to make some small example but I couldn't. It works fine for each part but not on the whole.

This is the full site:
http://192.185.67.199/~arielces/animations/#/commerce/main

Another thing I've noticed is that when in device mode, if you search the div with the magnifiers or just move the console from bottom to right, the content shows.

Comment: Nobody will be able to help you out with just an image of your problem. Please post a fiddle link or create a small basic prototype with the problem you are facing.

Comment: Hi Mechanicals, if I try to do it in a small prototype the problem does not occur, one of the tests I've done was to take every single piece and mounted separated, but it seems to happen when is all together. Thanks a lot for the comment, sorry I can't post something more specific. This is the full website http://192.185.67.199/~arielces/animations/#/commerce/details.

Comment: Not able to see the slider even in full desktop mode. the images are 404. Ping when the page is in a state to reproduce the issue which you have described.

Comment: Sorry, wrong link http://192.185.67.199/~arielces/animations/#/commerce/main. We added an $interval and that makes the slider to show up after the first timeout.